# Unexpected behaviour with Mongodb Mapreduce

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, mapreduce, reduce

I'm testing mapreduce function but I have unexpected behaviour:

I populated my collection with this simple for cycle:

```
for (i=0; i<10000; i++) {db.coll.insert({'a':1,'b':2})}
```

So I want count the documents with the same 'a' value (it's a test :-))
My map function is

```
map = "function() {  emit(this.a,this.b);}"
```

and reduce is:

```
reduce = "function (key,values) {return values.length;}"
```

Calling 
    db.coll.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out:{inline:1}})

the expected value is 10000 docs with the same 'a', it's ok?

But the result is:

```
db.coll.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out:{inline:1}})
{
    "results" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "value" : 101
            }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 892,
    "counts" : {
            "input" : 10000,
            "emit" : 10000,
            "reduce" : 100,
            "output" : 1
    },
    "ok" : 1,
}
```

Where is the problem??? Why value is 101? What is the meaning of reduce count in results?
Help me! Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

This result is very much expected because your reduce function is not actually doing any reducing.

Take a look at some basic map-reduce examples [HERE](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/) and see what the reduce function is actually doing.  It's somehow combining the values for each unique key.  Your reduce function is not doing that.

Comment: it may be non-obvious why you got 101 but it's actually quite predictable as the reduce function is not called just once for each key with a huge array of all values, but rather values are grouped and then reduce can be called multiple times to re-reduce already reduced value with new array of values - batches of 100 will result in 101 length of the values array on the last call.